# HTML tag not closing when injecting Lit

Tags: javascript, material-design, web-component, lit

My intention is to inject Lit into the md-menu tag (@material/web) as shown in the documentation:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <button
      class="anchor"
      ${ref(anchorRef)}
      @click=${() => this.menuRef.value.show()}>
    Click to open menu
  </button>
  <!--
    `has-overflow` is required when using a submenu which overflows the
    menu's contents
  -->
  <md-menu has-overflow ${ref(menuRef)} ${(el) => el.anchor = anchorRef.value}> <md-menu-item header="This is a header"></md-menu-item>
    <md-sub-menu-item header="this is a submenu item">
      <md-menu slot="submenu">
        <md-menu-item
          header="This is an item inside a submenu"></md-menu-item>
      </md-menu>
    </md-sub-menu>
  </md-menu>
</div>
```

Yet the md-menu tag doesn't close. What do I do with this for the HTML to render correctly.

Library link: [Github](https://github.com/material-components/material-web)

I have tried replacing `${(el) => el.anchor = anchorRef.value}` with `function (el) {el.anchor = anchorRef.value}`, yet the menu doesn't show up, still.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @EstusFlask I have taken your suggestion, but can you answer my question?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the docs where this example comes from? It lacks the context

Comment: @EstusFlask Here are links for the [library](https://github.com/material-components/material-web), the <md-menu> element is not fully documented, but the usage example can be found @ [blob/main/menu/menu.ts](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/blob/main/menu/menu.ts). I hope this helps

Comment: That example is Lit https://github.com/material-components/material-web/blob/main/menu/demo/stories.ts#L297-L309 , it needs to be rewritten to Vue. Cannot help at that point, I added the tag

Comment: Thank you for correction, it will help me pin-point the solution

Comment: Would you be able to add more context, or maybe even a sample showing the issue using the Lit playground (https://lit.dev/playground/)? From the question it's hard to understand what you mean by "inject Lit"? Where are you injecting Lit? It looks like you've provided a partial Lit template with no surrounding context. Thanks!